# How to run async function multiple times?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How can I run function multiple times?

I'd like to re-run loop so that program executes function a few more times. I understand that this is not correct approach. But surely there is workaround?

My code:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep


async def main(k):
    print(k)
    await sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        count_run = 3
        count_group = 3
        list_objects = list()

        for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

        list_func = [main(x) for x in list_objects]

        run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]

        loop = get_event_loop()

        for _ in range(count_run):
           for rg in run_groups:
               loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```

Now I am getting an error:

> RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine

Comment: "I understand that this is not correct approach."  Please explain.  Running a loop multiple times is a completely normal thing to do, so what do you think is not correct?

Comment: You create a list of awaitables by calling `main()` in `list_func` and then you create a bunch of slices of that list in `run_groups`, dividing the awaitable in groups of 3. You then start those groups one at a time, causing the awaitables to execute and return - once you have started every group and every awaitable has been awaited, you cannot await them again, you will have to create new awaitables.

Comment: @Grismar
How can I do that? Can you provide example in answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a list of awaitables by calling `main()` in `list_func` for each element of `list_objects` and then you create a bunch of slices of that list in `run_groups`, dividing the awaitable in groups of 3. You then start those groups one at a time, causing the awaitables to execute and return - once you have started every group and every awaitable has been awaited, you cannot await them again, you will have to create new awaitables.

The easiest way to fix your code to work, is to just change the order and include the creation of awaitables in the outer loop:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep


async def main(k):
    print(k)
    await sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_run = 3
    count_group = 3
    list_objects = list()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

    loop = get_event_loop()

    for _ in range(count_run):
        list_func = [main(x) for x in list_objects]

        run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
        for rg in run_groups:
           loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```

Note: I also fixed the problems with indentation in your code example, assuming that those were just a result of copy/paste issues into the question text.

The code now works because every awaitable in `list_func` only gets awaited once (in groups of 3) by the `gather` call, and all of them get awaited before the loop completes. In every iteration of the outer loop, a new list of awaitables gets created, to be able to repeat the process, since every awaitables can only be awaited once.

Another way to do it would be to create all the awaitables first and then cycle through all of them:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep


async def main(k):
    print(k)
    await sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_run = 3
    count_group = 3
    list_objects = list()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

    loop = get_event_loop()

    list_func = []
    for _ in range(count_run):
        list_func.extend([main(x) for x in list_objects])

    run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
    for rg in run_groups:
       loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```

From the difference in timing, you can tell that it now keeps executing in groups of 3, but continues "7 8 9", "10 1 2", etc. until it has gone through all 30.

The key difference is that `list_func` now contains all 30 awaitables before any of them get executed, instead of new awaitables getting created 3 times.

Comment: The first option is what me need! Thanks!